# Ecg Signal Analysis in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, signal-processing

I have AD8232 Ic from which i am receiving ECG Signal reading through Bluetooth Module and RP2040. Now i want to calculate the real-time heart-rate from ECG signal.

I found multiple Library in python which i can use by this flutter plugin chaquopy: ^0.0.19. which increases Size of app. Now i want to write whole code in dart

chaquopy: https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy/example

Pan_Tompkins_QRS_Detection: https://github.com/antimattercorrade/Pan_Tompkins_QRS_Detection

i want something like Pan_Tompkins_QRS_Detection in dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart implementation for Pan-Tompkins algorithm can be found in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PremchandGat/ECG-HeartRate-detection-Pan-Tompkins-algorithm-dart/tree/main)

For more info see [this](https://github.com/PremchandGat/ECG-HeartRate-detection-Pan-Tompkins-algorithm-dart/tree/main).

By this you will be able to calculate Heart-Rate and RR intervals from the row ECG signal.

https://github.com/PremchandGat/ECG-HeartRate-detection-Pan-Tompkins-algorithm-dart/tree/main